# Calculate values dynamically when updating a document in mongosh

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql, mongo-shell

I'm trying to update some documents using the mongo shell in mongodb compass. I'm using the updateMany function to do so. I want to calculate some values when updating the field.
for example

This is an example document

Account

```
  capital: 100,
  deposit: 0
```

I want to apply something like this

```
db.account.updateMany({}, {$set: {deposit: this.deposit + this.capital}})
```

but this is not working

Comment: `total : {$add:["$deposit","$capital"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [aggregated pipeline updates syntax](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to achieve this,
This is the only way to use existing document data within an update as a value. The syntax (in your case) remains quite similar, like so:

```
db.account.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    $set: {
      deposit: {
        $add: [
          "$deposit",
          "$capital"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mJpgRYaulSP)